# EasyAdmin 3 Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, symfony4, easyadmin3

How can I hide the button to create a comment of the page index? I dont need this button.

[image: Comments list]

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution.

```
 
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        return $actions
        ->remove(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::NEW)
        ;
    }
```